# Difference I2C Sensor Reading Raspberry Pi and Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c, smbus

I am using the Sensirion SFM3300 flow sensor and can read the correct values with the Arduino with the following code (I2C):

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.beginTransmission(byte(0x40));
  Wire.write(byte(0x10));
  Wire.write(byte(0x00));
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(100);
  Wire.requestFrom(0x40,2);
  uint16_t a = Wire.read();
  uint8_t  b = Wire.read();
  a = (a<<8) | b;
  float flow = ((float)a - 32768) / 120;
  Serial.println(flow);
}
```

But using the Raspberry Pi I have written the nearly the same code, hoping that it also will works.
This is the code:

```
from smbus2 import SMBus
import time
import numpy as np

address=0x40
bus = SMBus(1)

def write(value):
    bus.write_byte(address,value)

write(0x10)
write(0x00)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    a = np.uint16(bus.read_byte(0x40))
    b = np.uint8(bus.read_byte(0x40))
    a = (a<<8) | b
    flow = (float(a)-32768)/120
    print(flow)
```

The code really looks the same, but I only get -273,06666666666 as a return value. Does somebody knows where are the differences between Raspberry Pi and Arduino I2C and can help me to get the right values on the Pi?

Comment: What is the correct value expected? I would recommend to use `struct` unit instead of np requiring the ugly shift and or approach. This may be an endianness problem.

Comment: The expected value should be 0 (without any flow) and the sensor should react on the flow. But on the Raspbery I only get -273,0666666 with and without any float. How can I use struct in this case? Can you please help me.

Comment: Print the byte values first and see the result before calculations. Really 101 of `printf()` type of debugging :) Ah, yes, good recommendation in the answer. Have you read data sheet, by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. It would be nice if a I2C-expert could tell me why the following code is working instead of the python code above.

```
from fcntl import ioctl
from struct import unpack
from smbus import SMBus

address = 0x40

SMBus(1).write_byte_data(address,16,0)
i2c = open("/dev/i2c-1", "rb", buffering=0)
ioctl(i2c,0x0703,address)
i2c.read(3)

d0,d1,c = unpack('BBB', i2c.read(3))
d = d0 << 8 | d1
a = (float(d)-32768.)/120
print(a)
```

Comment: Ah, the `i2c-dev.c` on linux on i2cdev-read function has an [explanation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c#L112) on why it is needed. What `ioctl()` does is to sort of let the SDA float,  and if a slave exists it will pull the SDA down. This has the same effect as running linux command `i2cdetect -y 1` for detecting i2c addr. In fact, once you run `i2cdetect -y 1` once on newer Raspbian (as compare to earlier versions),  you will not need the `ioctl()` code any more and the normal SMBus code that I provide or you written will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read_i2c_block_data(addr, offset, numOfBytes)` method to get more than 1 byte of data from i2c. the return data is a list of bytes. So it is very easy to convert into an integer.

**Edited based on datasheet and Arduino sketch**

Here is the complete code for Python that should matched the Arduino example:

```
from SMBus2 import SMBus
import time

offset = 32768
scale = 120

addr = 0x40
cmd = [0x10, 0x00]

with SMBus(1) as bus:
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr, 0, cmd)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, 0, 3)
reading = block[0] * 256 + block[1]
crc = block[2]    # should do some crc check for error
flow = (reading - offset)/scale
print(flow)
```

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. Your code helps me, but I think, that the problem is on the I2C-Bus. With your code I also get a constant negative value of -273,.....With i2cset -y 1 0x40 0x10 and i2cset -y 1 0x40 0x00 I tried to start the measuring of the SFM3300 sensor. And with i2cget -y 1 0x40 I wanted to read out a byte, but I only get 0x00.

Comment: I think your formula wrong then. what you get is the flow value, it does not need to minus 32768 then divided by 120. The reason you get -273 is because the `value` = 0, so (0-32768)/120 = -273. I've edited my code.

Comment: It is from the official datasheet: https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/5_Mass_Flow_Meters/Application_Notes/Sensirion_Mass_Flo_Meters_SFM3xxx_I2C_Functional_Description.pdf

Comment: Based on the datasheet and you said that the Arduino code works, I edit my answer to include the complete python code. Again, I can't test it as I don't have the sensor and setup, you will have to run and debug it.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working on the Raspberry Pi. The flow is still -271,45 (with and without flow). The print of block[0] is always 0, of block[1] 194 and block[2] 37.

Comment: I think the mistake is in the write process. In my opinion the sensor never starts a measument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your read process in python is correct. Reading from port 40 two times is different from reading two bytes from port 40.

I suggest to use read_byte_data(0x40, 0, 2) and process that with `struct.unpack(">H")`.